# Draw a polygon in C

Tags: c, graphics, polygon, primitive, atan2

i need to draw a polygon of "n" sides given 2 points (the center and 1 of his vertex) just that i suck in math. I have been reading a lot and all this is what i have been able to figure it (i dont know if it is correct):

Ok, i take the distance between the 2 points (radius) with the theorem of Pythagoras:

```
sqrt(pow(abs(x - xc), 2) + pow(abs(y - yc), 2));
```

And the angle between this 2 points with atan2, like this:

```
atan2(abs(y - yc), abs(x - xc));
```

Where xc, yc is the center point and x, y is the only vertex know.

And with that data i do:

```
void polygon(int xc, int yc, int radius, double angle, int sides)
{
    int i;
    double ang = 360/sides; //Every vertex is about "ang" degrees from each other
    radian = 180/M_PI;
    int points_x[7]; //Here i store the calculated vertexs
    int points_y[7]; //Here i store the calculated vertexs

    /*Here i calculate the vertexs of the polygon*/
    for(i=0; i<sides; i++)
    {
        points_x[i] = xc + ceil(radius * cos(angle/radian));
        points_y[i] = yc + ceil(radius * sin(angle/radian));
        angle = angle+ang;
    }

    /*Here i draw the polygon with the know vertexs just calculated*/
    for(i=0; i<sides-1; i++)
        line(points_x[i], points_y[i], points_x[i+1], points_y[i+1]);
    line(points_y[i], points_x[i], points_x[0], points_y[0]);
}
```

The problem is that the program dont work correctly because it draw the lines not like a polygon.

Someone how know enough of math to give a hand? im working in this graphics primitives with C and turbo C.

---

Edit: i dont want to fill the polygon, just draw it.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want a filled polygon (in which case the answers about trangles may be relevant) or an unfilled one (where you simple want the perimeter lines as you suggest and drawing lines is all you need

Comment: Try to write a filled triangle renderer. Generally, filled polygons are drawn 1 horizontal scan line at a time, top to bottom. Your job is to determine the starting and stopping x coordinate for every scan line. Note that the edge of a polygon follows a straight line (hint, hint).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what `360/sides` actually returns if `sides` is not a factor of 360 (this is integer division - see what 360/7 actually returns).

There is no need to use degrees at all - use `2*Math_PI/(double)nsides` and work throughout in radians.

also you can omit the final line by using the modulus function (module nsides).

If you have more than 7 sides you will not be able to store all the points. You don't need to store all the points if you are simply drawing the polygon rather than storing it - just the last point and the current one.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using radians in all your calculations. Here's a complete program that illustrates how best to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI 3.141592653589

static void line (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    printf ("Line from (%3d,%3d) - (%3d,%3d)\n", x1, y1, x2, y2);
}

static void polygon (int xc, int yc, int x, int y, int n) {
    int lastx, lasty;
    double r = sqrt ((x - xc) * (x - xc) + (y - yc) * (y - yc));
    double a = atan2 (y - yc, x - xc);
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        lastx = x; lasty = y;
        a = a + PI * 2 / n;
        x = round ((double)xc + (double)r * cos(a));
        y = round ((double)yc + (double)r * sin(a));
        line (lastx, lasty, x, y);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    polygon (0,0,0,10,4);   // A diamond.
    polygon (0,0,10,10,4);  // A square.
    polygon (0,0,0,10,8);   // An octagon.
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs (no fancy graphics here, but you should get the idea):

```
===
Line from (  0, 10) - (-10,  0)
Line from (-10,  0) - (  0,-10)
Line from (  0,-10) - ( 10,  0)
Line from ( 10,  0) - (  0, 10)
===
Line from ( 10, 10) - (-10, 10)
Line from (-10, 10) - (-10,-10)
Line from (-10,-10) - ( 10,-10)
Line from ( 10,-10) - ( 10, 10)
===
Line from (  0, 10) - ( -7,  7)
Line from ( -7,  7) - (-10,  0)
Line from (-10,  0) - ( -7, -7)
Line from ( -7, -7) - (  0,-10)
Line from (  0,-10) - (  7, -7)
Line from (  7, -7) - ( 10,  0)
Line from ( 10,  0) - (  7,  7)
Line from (  7,  7) - (  0, 10)
```

I've written the `polygon` function as per your original specification, passing in just the two co-ordinates. As an aside, you don't *want* those `abs` calls in your calculations for radius and angle because:

- they're useless for radius (since `-n`<sup>`2`</sup> = `n`<sup>`2`</sup> for all `n`).
- they're bad for angle since that will force you into a specific quadrant (wrong starting point).

Comment: Not enough digits.  Try 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756482337867831652712019091456485669234603486104543266482133936072602491412737245870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919530921861173819326117931051185480744623799627495673518857527248912279381830119491298336733624406566430860213949463952247371907021798

Comment: @Pete, I can't tell whether you're trying to be funny ot not. But even the approximation 355/113 is enough to pinpoint a car (3m) on a circle the size of the Earth. I suspect your version may be enough to locate an atom in a sphere the size of the solar system, probably a little bit of overkill for drawing on a monitor.

Comment: I think more than 8 digits would be excessive for this sort of work--so pardon my lame attempt at a joke :)

Comment: Full double precision is about 17 decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to just give you the answer, but I have some advice. First, learn how line drawing works INSIDE AND OUT. When you have this down, try to write a filled triangle renderer.
Generally, filled polygons are drawn 1 horizontal scan line at a time, top to bottom. You're job is to determine the starting and stopping x coordinate for every scan line. Note that the edge of a polygon follows a straight line (hint, hint)... :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to draw a filled poly I guess?

If you're going to try to draw the polys using a line primitive, you're going to have a lot of pain coming to you. dicroce actually gave you some very good advice on that front.

Your best bet is to find a primitive that fills for you and supply it a coordinates list. It's up to you to determine the coordinates to give it.

Comment: Why do you assume it has to be filled? The question makes no mention of that. In fact it specifically attempts to draw the outline of the polygon, not a filled version.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main trouble is: `atan2(abs(y - yc), abs(x - xc));` is giving you radians, not degrees, just convert it to degrees and try.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* all angles in radians */
double ainc = PI*2 / sides;
int x1, y1;
for (i = 0; i <= sides; i++){
    double a = angle + ainc * i;
    int x = xc + radius * cos(a);
    int y = yc + radius * sin(a);
    if (i > 0) line(x1, y1, x, y);
    x1 = x; y1 = y;
}
```

Or, you could save the points in an array and call the DrawPoly routine if you've got one.

If you want a filled polygon, call FillPoly if you've got one.